# Azure Function App - PHP $_GET / $_POST / $_REQUEST

Tags: php, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

There doesn't appear to be any clear documentation for collecting GET/POST requests to Azure Functions running in PHP.

I've tried the usual var_dump and variances of those to collect the data. Including, when integrating a HTTP request as an input, defining the variable as "req".

Even specifying $_REQUEST['req'] doesn't seem to load POST/GET data into the function.

As an aside, if you happen to know how to load data into an integrated DocumentDB output, that would equally be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access request parameters/headers by referencing `REQ_QUERY_<NAME>`/`REQ_HEADERS_<NAME>` environment variables. For example:

```
<?php
  /* request body */
  $body = file_get_contents(getenv('req'));
  $body = rtrim($body, "\n\r");
  fwrite(STDOUT, "PHP script processed request body '$body'\r\n");

  /* access query parameter 'test' */
  $test = getenv('req_query_test');
  fwrite(STDOUT, "Parameter Test='$test'\r\n");

  /* access header 'test' */
  $test = getenv('req_headers_test');
  fwrite(STDOUT, "Header Test='$test'\r\n");
?>
```

Similarly, if your function has route parameters, they can be accessed via `REQ_PARAMS_<NAME>` environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't get a response, so kept investigating. It seems the default "req" value only supplies the Request Body on POST requests when using `file_get_contents(getenv('req'))`

This is particularly unhelpful if you're looking for actual request parameters in a POST or a GET.

You should find everything you need by `var_dump($_SERVER)` it's messy, but you get the values you need. If anyone else finds a more elegant way of attaining the values, post away.

As an aside, dumping out to DocumentDB bindings can be done by;
`file_put_contents(getenv('VariableName'), "{ \"JSON\" : \"JSON Details\" } ");`